# Content of div is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]

The content of the div is not working as responsive manner.When I am trying to reduce the size of the browse then inner content of the div is coming out.

I want to make this responsive means when i will reduce the size of the browser after a threshold point it will come as single line content and nothing will come out.

here is my code which one i have written ===>

## abc.htm

```css
.projects{
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  height: 110% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  background-color: #363636;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;

}
.project_heading{
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
  left: 40%;
  font-family:Courier, Monaco, monospace;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.skill_sets{
position: absolute;
height: 400px;
width: 200px;
left: 70%;
top: 20%;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.skills_heading{
  position: absolute;
  top:25%;
  
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  font-family:Courier, Monaco, monospace;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  /*letter-spacing: 8px;*/
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  margin: 40 0px;
}
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="cc.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content" class="content">
     <!-- <div id="doing_box_closed" class="doing_box_closed">
     </div> -->
    
     <div id="projects" class="projects">
      <p id="project_heading" class="project_heading">PROJECTS</p>
      <div id="skill_sets" class="skill_sets">
       <p id="skills_heading" class="skills_heading">Skills</p>
      </div>
     
     </div>
     
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have `left` in percents and `width` in pixels, what else did you expect? Can you share a mockup of what it should look like?

Comment: also you should not need so many absolute positions. It's not a good way to create a layout. Consider using flexbox

Comment: okk i got ur point ....the problem was in width pixels ....thanks :) @mizurnix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your `.skill_sets` Try this:

```
.skill_sets {
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 400px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    /* left: 70%; */
    top: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

When you use `position:absolute` it forces the position of an element and you are bundling it with `left:70%` and also with a definite `width:200px` so its obvious that it'll go out of the container.

Comment: ...at 1st sill_set will be in left 70%...when i will reduce the browser size then after crossing threshold value it will be in vertical line...like at 1st it will print the content of project then print the skill_set ..... okk??